# perl to convert xls to xml

Tags: xml, perl, xlsx

I do have this script that convert xls to xml, my excel file has to or three columns, the xmls format should be like this `<testcase name="Test1"> but it prints <testcase name>test-1</testcase name>`

per script is like this:

```
 my $file = 'myfile.xls';
 my @columns = ('testcase name', 'summary', 'preconditions');
 my $xls = XML::Excel->new({column_headings => \@columns});
 print $file;

 $xls->parse_doc($file);
 $xls->declare_xml({version => '1.0',
 encoding => 'UTF-8', standalone => 'yes'});
 $xls->print_xml('test.xml',
                    {
                    file_tag    => 'testcases',
                    parent_tag  => "testcase"
                    }
            );
```

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think XML::Excel can do what you require, it is a simple module and also quite old (2001). Here is a way to do it using [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) (which XML::Excel uses) and [XML::Writer](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Writer). If you need to write to a file you can change the 'OUTPUT' option - see the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Writer).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use XML::Writer;

my @columns = ('name', 'summary', 'preconditions');
my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('myfile.xls') or die $parser->error();
my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet(0);
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
my @data;
for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
    my %hash;
    for my $col (0 .. $#columns) {
        my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
        $hash{$columns[$col]} = $cell->value();
    }
    push(@data,\%hash)
}

my $writer = XML::Writer->new(OUTPUT => 'self', DATA_MODE => 1);
$writer->xmlDecl();
$writer->startTag('testcases');
for my $row (@data) {
    $writer->startTag('testcase', name => $row->{'name'});
    $writer->dataElement('summary', $row->{'summary'});
    $writer->dataElement('preconditions', $row->{'preconditions'});
    $writer->endTag('testcase');
}
$writer->endTag('testcases');
$writer->end;
print $writer->to_string;
```

Sample output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<testcases>
<testcase name="test1">
<summary>summary1</summary>
<preconditions>preconditions1</preconditions>
</testcase>
<testcase name="test2">
<summary>summary2</summary>
<preconditions>preconditions2</preconditions>
</testcase>
</testcases>
```

Comment: thanks but that output is not what I wanted, the out I got is:             <  records>
        <record>
                <test-1>test-2</test-1>   and I wanted to something like this <testcase name="Test1">

Comment: @user2912312 that doesn't make any sense, I am not outputting any tags called 'records', 'record' or 'test-1' in my code. I have updated to show sample output.

Comment: @user2912312 Sounds like you are still using XML::Excel as 'records' and 'record' are the default tags for that module's output.

Comment: Thanks.. my bad sign of getting old and you were right I was using XML::Excel after removing it printed the way I wanted..thanks again, you are life saver..

Comment: tangent- just want to let you know the solution does not work if file extension is xlsx, works perfectly with xls but not xlxs :-(

Comment: Have a look at Spreadsheet::XLSX or Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX both of which you should be able to drop in replace